# How to run a NodeJS file from a url request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, http

I want to run a NodeJS file index.js from url request, whenever I hit this url like localhost:8080 it automatically run the index.js file.

Comment: Can you give some more information? What is your goal? Do you want to use it like a normal web server?

Comment: @Bolphgolph, I made a program in nodejs and now I want expose it as an API, so any one can use this program by using this url

Comment: You can use the default `npm start app.js`. This will make the Application accessible to everyone in the same network. I would recommend that you use some kind of processmanager like this: http://pm2.keymetrics.io/ . If you want to make it accessible to the internet, you will have to set up a "real" web server.

Comment: Try creating restful apis.

Comment: export whatever function is in your index js as a module via module exports and require it in you routing file and call the function from there. if it is not the same project you can either run a sh file which calls this file via 'node ../path/index.js' or you import it as a npm package.

Comment: how about some research before asking: https://www.google.com/search?q=node.js+create+web+service&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-e

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to do, but maybe something simple like this?

```
var yourSuperAwesomeAPI = require('./yourSuperAwesomeAPI.js');
var http = require('http');
    http.createServer(function (req, res) {
        switch(req.url){
            case '/':         res.write('website.com');          break;
            case '/about_us': res.write('website.com/about_us'); break;
            case '/api':  
               yourSuperAwesomeAPI();
               break;
            default:          res.write('website.com/error_404');
        }
        res.end();
}).listen(8080);
```

You can just run it like that. You could also get the url parameters, so you can take input, so you may want to check out the [url](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html) module for nodejs or you can just google how to get url parameters.

As I said i'm not sure if this is what you want to do, if you want to just return a .js file that is a bit different, but generally pretty similar.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [child process](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) module of nodejs to execute any shell commands or scripts within nodejs.

Create an executable bash file like:

myProcess.sh >

`node <path-to-file>/index.js`

And at your URL handler you can initiate the call like below:

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
var yourscript = exec('sh myProcess.sh',
  (error, stdout, stderr) => {
    if (error !== null) {
      console.log(`exec error: ${error}`);
    }
  }
)
```